# Обрезать текст по вертикали и добавить многоточие в конце

Tags: jquery, css

Прошу помочь с [такой](http://jsfiddle.net/rsga31u3/3/) проблемой:
HTML

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <span class='title'>Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок Заголовок </span>
    <span class='description'>Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание Описание </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrap {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    font: 1.5em Verdana;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1;
}

.description {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    font: 1em Verdana;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Нужно, чтобы в зависимости от величины заголовка - количества строк, которое он занимает, текст описания сокращался-увеличивался. Если полностью не влазит - в конце добавлялось многоточие. Блок обёртки фиксированной высоты, а блоки с заголовком и описанием тянутся.

Спасибо.

Comment: Вроде гугление по line-clamp вам поможет: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ , https://github.com/ftlabs/ftellipsis - судя по быстрому гуглению, кросс-браузерной поддержки на уровне CSS нет, есть JS библиотеки и какие-то варианты на чистом CSS (но в них не вчитывался).

Comment: Спасибо. Есть варианты на JS, но они отталкиваются от фиксированной высоты блока, в котором нужно текст обрезать. А в трюках, которые вы предложили, я так понял, используется градиент последнего слова, которое режется. Многоточие как-то ближе к пунктуации русского языка и эстетичнее что ли.

Answer (score 1):

Вашему контейнеру с описанием добавьте css3 свойство `text-overflow: ellipsis`. Хочу обратить внимание, что это свойство будет работать, только если у контейнера задано свойство `overflow`, как `hidden`, `auto` или `scroll`. 
П.с. для оперы версий 9-11 используйте префикс `-text-overflow.`

Comment: ГенераторКачества, cпасибо. Но не работает, обычно text-overflow: ellipsis работает только по горизонтали, когда текст в одну строчку и не влазит по ширине

Comment: Хм... Есть плагин для jQuery, он может делать то, что вам нужно. jTruncate называется. Как будет обрезаться текст там можно настроить по усмотрению. Но он будет работать корректно, только если у вас в описании будет один абзац текста. Также можно рассмотреть возможность обрезки текста на php, где в ваших руках полная свобода действий.

Comment: Сейчас подумал, можно посчитать сколько символов влазит в ваш контейнер, после чего на js обрезать весь текст до последнего пробела, на css через псевдоэлемент :after добавить многоточие. Думаю, такое решение будет проще и легче использования плагинов. Ещё вариант, можно не считать количество символов, а через тот же js получить высоту текста с необходимой шириной контейнера, обрезать текст и, опять же через псевдоэлемент добавить многоточие

Comment: Спасибо. Да, я тоже думал отталкиваться от высоты заголовка и выставлять соответствующую высоту блоку с описанием. Ещё приходила мысль, как и Вы верно подметили, сделать на PHP - но тут можно оттолкнуться только от количества символов или количества слов - через условие обрезать нужное количество символов в описании, отталкиваясь от количества символов в заголовке и пристыковывать многоточие. Но из-за того, что диапазон символов в строке будет далёк от точного, то могут быть вопросы с корректностью и универсальностью метода. Наверное или нет?

Comment: Посчитайте по максимуму символов и отнимите штук 10 с запасом. Там многоточие и вставите. Я думаю, в вашей задаче так будет проще всего

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Буду пробовать. Думаю, PHP даёт самое элегантное, надёжное и производительное решение!